# Sharepoint 2013 survey list doesn't render all results

Tags: managed-metadata, survey-list

We have a survey created on a SharePoint 2013 site collection. One of the questions is a Managed Metadata column. When an owner with full permissions clicks on the link for a graphical summary of responses, (summary.aspx) all of the questions render results except for the one with the Managed Metadata.

If I look at the view, it renders. I am a site collection administrator. Where can permissions be granted for the "owners"?

-Doug